# Finding the max and min of a BIT in linear or sub-linear time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit

I have to perform a series of range updations on an array, i.e., adding or subtracting some constant to and from a range. After that I have to find the RANGE of the final array, i.e., (max-min). Initially the numbers are 1 to n.

I'm using Binary Indexed Tree. Each update is in log N. I want to know if there is a way to find thus RANGE (or max and min) in O(n) or less time. Conventionally, it takes O(n log n).

Comment: Given an array, you can find the min and max in O(n) time. How did you analyze O(nlogn)?

Comment: I think it takes O(logn) for finding ranges in Binary Index Trees "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree " and not O(nlongn)

Comment: I'm using BIT which operates upon frequencies. The original array is unchanged. I just have to find the RANGE after a series of updations.

Comment: @Aditya By "RANGE" I mean the mathematical term, finding maximum-minimum of the supposedly final array.

Comment: Are you doing the following: Update queries, GetRange, Update queries, GetRange etc right?

Comment: @Roman No, a series of update queries and then finding RANGE.

Answer (score 0):

You need direct indexed access to the array elements since you need to address them for doing the incremental updates.

You also need to maintain a min-heap and max-heap.

When you update an element, you also need to update the corresponding entries in the two heaps. So you need to store the pointers into corresponding elements in the two heaps in the array.

Creating the original heap is O(n) and any modifications are O(lg(N)).

Comment: I'm updating in a range. So how can I update the corresponding entries in the heap, unless in O(N log N). I can't afford O(N log N).

Comment: Every time you update you incur the cost of log(N) for the heap-update. So if the range is of size "k" then you incur O(k lg(N)) cost which lends itself well to incremental updates assuming k << N. Of course if k and N are in the same order of magnitude you can regenerate the heap in O(N) instead of doing incremental updates. Since you seem to know the size of the range which is being updated (k) and its relationship with N, you can decide wether to make heap again (O(N)) or to do incremental updates (delete/reinsert). make_heap is 3*N http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap

Comment: The number of update queries over a range is also very large, (say k). If each time the range is 1..N, the complexity of make_heap would be O(kN). The maximum I can afford is O(k log N) or likewise.

Comment: If k is the same order of magnitude as N, you start with a *fresh* heap, instead of incremental updates. make_heap in C++ STL is typically 3*N. You use the incremental updates only if k<<N. What this means is that you do NOT update the heap while the range is being updated; you only update the heap after all the range values are updated. You seem to know the range (k) so you decide up front whether you want to use incremental updates (after every one of k) or a single make_heap (after all k updates are done).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort the array once?  Then adding or subtracting a constant from the whole array still gives the same ordering, as does multiplying by a positive number.  Maybe there's more to the picture though.

Comment: The incremental changes are not over all elements but a subset of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost 2 years old, hence I am not sure if this answer is going to help much. Anyway...
I have never used BIT to answer minimum or maximum queries. And here there are range queries, which change a lot of numbers all at once. So the maximums and minimums also get updated. As far as I know, I have never seen BITs to be used in queries other than point query, range sum search, etc.
In general, segment trees provide better option for searching for minimum and maximum values. After performing all updates, you can find those in O(lg n) time. However, during updates, you must update the min max values for each node, which can be done using Lazy Propagation. The update cost is O(lg n).
To sum up, if m lg n < n for your application, you can go with Segment tree, albeit with more space.